# Adding data from Firebase Storage to an ArrayList using StorageReference in Java

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage

I'm trying to retrieve folders' names from FireBase Storage and to add them to my ArrayList:

```
public class NewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>()

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_themes);

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(NewActivity.this);
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

    StorageReference reference = storage.getReference("themes");
    reference.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
            for (StorageReference prefix: listResult.getPrefixes()) {
                articles.add(new Article(prefix.getName()));
            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

At the end, after Activity stop running, I still have an empty ArrayList, no any folder's name was saved to it (in reality reference "themes" has several folders). I have already read, that "addOnSuccessListener is asynchronous and returns immediately. The callback is invoked some time later. And also for getting data - Tasks.whenAll() should be used". But I don't have any idea how can I implement it into my code...  I need your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that Firebase Storage operations are asynchronous, and the code you provided may not guarantee that the **articles** list is populated when you expect it to be. To ensure that your **articles** list is populated only after all the data has been retrieved from Firebase Storage, you can use `Tasks.whenAll()` to handle the asynchronous calls. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve that:

```
public class NewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_themes);

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(NewActivity.this);
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

        StorageReference reference = storage.getReference("themes");
        reference.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
                List<Task<Void>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

                for (StorageReference prefix : listResult.getPrefixes()) {
                    Task<Void> task = getArticleNameAndAddToList(prefix);
                    tasks.add(task);
                }

                Tasks.whenAll(tasks).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        // Now, the articles list is populated.
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private Task<Void> getArticleNameAndAddToList(StorageReference reference) {
        TaskCompletionSource<Void> taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<>();
        
        reference.getName().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String name) {
                articles.add(new Article(name));
                taskCompletionSource.setResult(null);
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                taskCompletionSource.setException(e);
            }
        });
        
        return taskCompletionSource.getTask();
    }
}
```

In this code:

> **1.** We create a list of tasks for retrieving folder names using nameTask.
>
> **2.** We use onSuccessTask to create a new task for each folder name
> retrieval. This allows you to add the folder name to the articles list
> and continue the chain of tasks.
>
> **3.** We use Tasks.whenAll(tasks) to wait for all the tasks to complete,
> ensuring that the articles list is fully populated before proceeding
> with any further actions.
>
> **4.** Now, the articles list will be populated with folder names only after
> all the data has been successfully retrieved from Firebase Storage.